# After updating the document By findOneAndUpdate both documents become same

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to update a document by a field name(riderUserId) with findOneAndUpdate

What it does is instead of updating a document by riderUserId

```
updateProfile: function(req, res) {
        var riderUserID = req.params.riderUserID;
        profileModel.findOneAndUpdate(riderUserID, req.body,
            { overwrite: true, new: true }, (error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                res.json(error);
                console.error(error);
                return;
            }
            res.json(response);
       });
    },
```

This is my model

```
var profileSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    surname: { type: String },
    gender: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    riderUserId: { type: String },
    mobileNumber: { type: Number },
    birthYear: { type: Number },
    nationality: { type: String },
    idNumber: { type: String },
    quickDescription: { type: String },
    numberPlate: { type: String },
    make: { type: Number },
    model: { type: String },
    memberType: { type: String },
    accountHolderName: { type: String },
    accountNumber: { type: Number },
    nameOfBank: { type: String },
    branchCode: { type: Number },
    profilePicture: { type: String },
    carPicture: { type: String },
    music: { type: String },
    conversations: { type: String },
    pets: { type: String },
    smoking: { type: String },
    emailVerification: { type: Boolean },
    phoneVerification: { type: Boolean },
    idVerification: { type: Boolean },
 });
```

And here are two document,

```
     { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bed37dc84fd420002791e0c"), 
    "email" : "shoba.hasini@gmail.com", 
    "riderUserId" : "ZH8irbzGt8WULt2lFSIU5J48Alz2", 
    "name" : "Shoba", 
    "surname" : "Hasini", 
    "gender" : "", 
    "mobileNumber" : null, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bed37f484fd420002791e0d"), 
    "email" : "kartikajas@gmail.com", 
    "riderUserId" : "e1FUpfsDiwSVxcz50ZbhjWKfKGM2", 
    "name" : "Karthik", 
    "surname" : "Keyan", 
    "gender" : "", 
    "mobileNumber" : null, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

After updating the document By findOneAndUpdate both documents become same

,  {

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bed37dc84fd420002791e0c"), 
    "name" : "Karthik", 
    "surname" : "Keyan", 
    "gender" : "male", 
    "email" : "kartikajas@gmail.com", 
    "riderUserId" : "e1FUpfsDiwSVxcz50ZbhjWKfKGM2", 
    "mobileNumber" : NumberInt(90087),     
    "idVerification" : false
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bed37f484fd420002791e0d"), 
    "email" : "kartikajas@gmail.com", 
    "riderUserId" : "e1FUpfsDiwSVxcz50ZbhjWKfKGM2", 
    "name" : "Karthik", 
    "surname" : "Keyan", 
    "gender" : "", 
    "mobileNumber" : null, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Why is it not updating one document with the riderId e1FUpfsDiwSVxcz50ZbhjWKfKGM2

Comment: For brevity I have deleted few fields.

Comment: In your code, you're passing `riderUserID` (Which is a string) to `findOneAndUpdate`. But mongoose actually takes an `Object` as input. You may need to pass an object like `{ _id: riderUserID }`. If your riderUserID is a `mongo object id`.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: rideruserid is not a mongo object id

Comment: From your `Schema` I can see that your `riderUserID` is a string. replace `findOneAndUpdate(riderUserID, ...` with `findOneAndUpdate({ riderUserID }, ...` and try.

Comment: Would you like to answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n your code, you're passing `riderUserID` (Which is a string) to `findOneAndUpdate`. But mongoose actually takes an `Object` as search query param. You may need to pass an object like { _id: riderUserID }. If your riderUserID is a mongo object id.

From your Schema I can see that your riderUserID is a string. replace `findOneAndUpdate(riderUserID, ...` with `findOneAndUpdate({ riderUserID }, ...` and try.

For more info

> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate